# Emulate different viewport sizes within page

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I have a web site that uses separate templates for “desktop” and “mobile” visitors; the site includes “switch to desktop/mobile” links to allow visitors to change viewing modes. I am working on a new, **responsive** UI element whose HTML and CSS can work equally well on both desktop and mobile templates. For the purposes of my example below, let’s suppose it’s a new page header.

Example markup of desktop page:

```
<html class="desktop">
  <head>…</head>
  <body>
    <div class="responsive_nav">Navigation bar content</div>
    <div>Desktop body content</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example mobile page markup:

```
<html class="mobile">
  <head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    …
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="responsive_nav">Navigation bar content</div>
    <div>Mobile body content</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Because my mobile templates include a meta viewport tag, and desktop pages do not, when a user with a mobile browser loads a page in mobile mode, the page will be rendered inside a [layout viewport](https://quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html) appropriate to the user agent’s screen size. I.e., she’ll see the responsive header’s “small”/“mobile” breakpoint.

If she switches to desktop mode, loading a page template with no meta viewport tag, she’ll see a desktop-sized page zoomed way out, with the new header rendered at its “large”/“desktop” breakpoint.

**My question is: what would it take for the responsive header to appear at its “zoomed in”/“small”/“mobile” breakpoint while keeping the rest of the desktop template's content zoomed out?**

Put another way, have part of the page (the header) behave as if the meta viewport tag were present (small, device-appropriate layout viewport size), and the rest of the page behave as if there were no meta viewport tag (large, “desktop-sized” layout viewport).

Put yet another way, have part of the page behave as if we were at one (small/mobile) screen breakpoint, and another part of the page behave like the large/desktop breakpoint.

### Solutions I have tried that don’t work:

- Using the non-standard CSS `zoom` property on the header. This makes the header bigger, and keeps it inside the screen width, but does not change which breakpoint is applied. The effect is a larger, squished desktop header content instead of the mobile breakpoint.
- Use CSS `transform: scale`. This is worse than `zoom`, because it doesn’t cause a breakpoint change *and* the header is not constrained within the screen (visual viewport).

### Possible, but undesirable, solution: giant navbar

Make a giant-sized variant of the navbar’s small breakpoint so that when viewed zoomed out on a mobile device, it looks like it’s actually “normal mobile size”. i.e., make a copy of the smartphone breakpoint and scale it up (font sizes, widths, margins, everything).

I think this requires a lot of duplicate CSS, and possibly duplicate markup, and barring some magic with `vh/vw`, probably can’t be done in a way that exactly matches the screen size.

Are there any other possibilities?